# How to do many whois look-ups via Windows?

Tags: windows, whois

I am used to using whois.sc/domaintools by just typing http://whois.sc/superuser.com via the browser, but I am liking less and less that they are selling private historical whois information for money. I am mainly doing whois look-ups for personal sites so using whois.sc isn't exactly in my interest if I value my privacy.

- Is there a way to do whois look-ups via software in Windows?
- Are there alternative whois site that:

  - offer quick whoises via a simple url e.g. xxwhois.tld/domain
  - do not require captcha solving each time

Those 2 things are great about whois.sc. I know that whois information is public, but I don't want to generate a new historical whois entry at the domaintools database every time I use their site as there is no opt-out available.

I am afraid this question might be closed, because it's not really a question for superuser.com, so apologies in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are dedicated clients for all platforms, including various versions of Windows, but basically, just `telnet whois.internic.net 43` and type in the domain name you are interested in.  The result will be a referral, i.e. a pointer to another server you should connect to to obtain the final result, or possibly yet another referral.

There is a large number of web-based whois services; most domain registration services offer one, or you can try e.g. http://who.is/

Answer (score -1):

There are some whois clients on Windows (e.g., Microsoft Sysinternals Whois). However, the ones I tested do not show a good coverage of whois servers, do not support IDNs or they do not follow automatically references between servers.

The best whois client I used is the one which is included in Debian Linux, so I decided to made a port to Windows. The source can be found [here](https://github.com/mfornasa/whois) and the first release is [here](https://github.com/mfornasa/whois/releases/tag/v5.1.1_win32_alpha2).

Comment: This needs to be flagged for deletion.

Comment: @Sickest What's wrong with it?

Comment: looks like spam, software recommendation, it doesn't answer the question in any fashion other then 2 links with very limited text (poor quality). that's off the top of my head.

Comment: I think if you expand on the abilities of your app, instead of just a link, it would help this post. I do not feel it should be SPAM flagged, but I also haven't downloaded the app